# How do I migrate an Assembla project (Issues and Source) to Github?

Tags: github, migration, issue-tracking, assembla

I wanna migrate a project from Assembla to Github with all its tickets and sources.

**Sources**

The sources are not the problem because I can push it easily to the new environment.

**Tickets**

My problem is the linking between commits that includes an issue number (e.g. `#123 Increased build number`) to the related issue / ticket.

Github counts everything in its ID (tickets, pull requests, etc). That means that it seems to be highly unlikely that my `Assembla ticket #123` will be my `Github issue #123` and therefore the connection between he commit and the ticket will break.

I tried to export all my tickets from Assembla but label `Backup successfully scheduled.` stays for hours now.

**Question**

Please correct me if this assumption is false. My question at all is, if someone could provide an idea how to solve the problem. It seems to be that there is no official importer to Github or exporter from Assembla.

Comment: Just wondering, did you migrate tickets from assembla to github?

Comment: Yes and no. I had an script that used the export from Assembla and the web service from GitHub. but Assembla changed it format, that means my code no longer works. Further the problem is, how to map multi-git but single ticket assembla spaces to GitHub.  That means, that I have currenty no working solution for my scenario.

Comment: Ok. Just wondering if you still need this migration of tickets and how many of them? I'm thinking to write utility which consume assembla api and github api to migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, official importer from assembla to github does not exists. So you need to do it manually(implement utility) consuming assembla api to pull information and upload it to github. You can try to find existing hand made tools [here](https://github.com/search?q=assembla%20to%20github)

Answer (score 0):

> Please correct me if this assumption is false. My question at all is,
>   if someone could provide an idea how to solve the problem. It seems to
>   be that there is no official importer to Github or exporter from
>   Assembla.

I couldn't find an answer or a solution that included migrating both source code and issues (tickets). Here is [an article I wrote](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5247083/Migrating-from-Assemble-to-Github-using-automation) with a complete solution.

> Github counts everything in its ID (tickets, pull requests, etc). That
>   means that it seems to be highly unlikely that my Assembla ticket #123
>   will be my Github issue #123 and therefore the connection between he
>   commit and the ticket will break.

I found a solution for that as well. There was a need to create an automatic script (in Python) for associating Assembla Tickets' attached files with these files after being added to the Github's Issues, and that includes:
- Handling updates in Tickets
- Handling labels
- Handling references between Tickets
- Handling references to Commits.
- Preserving the original Tickets numbering after migrating them as Issues to Github.

The process includes:

- Creating a backup of all Tickets (which unfortunately doesn't contain any images or attached files). Following your question, you need to go to Settings and schedule a backup for your tickets, and then visit again this page and download it. The backup should be a .bak file.
  [image]
- Importing the Assembla repository from Github's new repository.
  [image]
- Customizing the scripts, as explained in this article.
- Running our script which handles all the rest via automation.

Optionally:

- Updating existing Issues in a Github Repo